# ssh can't connet between two servers by ssh with changing default port

Tags: ssh, server, port

I have two servers, I want to connect server1 to server2. I've configured the firewall between them, and they could be connected before I changed server2's default port.

Now I can connect to server2 by ssh on my mac, but when I try to connect to server2 on server1, I get this error:

ssh: connect to host [ip_address] port 49645: Connection refused

What's else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What is the current firewall configuration? Without more context, it seems you may need to configure the firewall to allow port 49645 incoming on server2. If you're getting a "connection refused," make sure that on server2 ssh localhost:49645 works and that ssh is running with your settings.

Comment: I'm sure that server2 has been configured the firewall to to allow port 49645 incoming. I can connect to server2 from my local macbook. but can not from server1.